# boolean attributes in BeautifulSoup4 output

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I use `<script async ...>` for asynchronous loading of JavaScript files.  When I load the file into Python using BeautifulSoup4, make some unrelated change, and save the result, BeautifulSoup4 turns my `<script>` statements into `<script async="" ...>`.  Is there a way to prevent BeautifulSoup4 from appending the superfluous `...=""`?

Minimal "working" example:

```
In [1]: import bs4

In [2]: str(bs4.BeautifulSoup('<script async src="test.js"/>', 'html.parser'))
Out[2]: '<script async="" src="test.js"></script>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set the 'async' attribute to `None` if you want it to have no value.

```
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup('<script async src="test.js"/>', 'html.parser')
for tag in soup.find_all('script', async=''):
    tag['async'] = None
print(str(soup))
```

> `<script async src="test.js"></script>`